# How to match a string with values in a object array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects as

```
array = [{"key": "English", "value": "en-ca"}, 
{"key": "French", "value": "fr-ca"}];
```

I am detecting the browser language using the following:

```
var brwsrlang = window.navigator.language;
```

I need to match the obtained browser language(brwsrlang) with the value in my array and return the matching string **"en-ca"**.

For example:
If my broswer language is "en-ca" it should return true or else false.
I tried the following way. But, I want to make it work with the array values.

```
const x = brwsrlang.match( /[a-z]|-/g).join('');
```

This gives me the following result.

```
Output x=:
"en-ca"
```

But, I don't want to match it with all the alphabets. I just want it to check from the given array. I want to replace the regex with my array values.

Comment: Why are the objects `{ key: 'English', value: 'en-ca' }` instead of `{ "english": "en-ca" }`?

Comment: `const inArray = array.some(language=> language.value.toLowerCase() === brwsrlang.toLowerCase());`

Answer (score 1):

I'd turn the array into an object, eg into

```
{
  'en-ca': 'English',
  'fr-ca': 'French',
}
```

Ideally, do this *once*, in advance - eg, restructure your *source code* to an object of this structure.

Then just use bracket notation to look up the language on the object.

```
const languagesObj = Object.fromEntries(
  array.map(
    ({ key, value }) => [value, key]
  )
);
const thisLanguage = languagesObj[window.navigator.language];
```